# Site tile is wrong in search engine

Tags: wordpress, search

When I search my website in Google the website tile is shown but my WordPress blog is also shown after my site tile. Why is my WordPress blog appearing after the site title? I didn't mention it on my site then why its shown in search engine.
this is my site link:https://aspaceforme.net/
that is the header code:

" >

    
    ">

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Comment: Google chooses what it shows in the search results. It recently decided it would change your Title when it sees fit - it no longer only uses your SEO Title. Also, because you use Yoast, Google knows about all the pages - https://aspaceforme.net/sitemap_index.xml - and for whatever reason, it's decided to show your blog. Keep in mind that the search results you see will be different to other people - search results now take into account your search history and location. Because you've likely searched your own site before, Google probably thinks you want to see more info than the average person.

Comment: Any solution to remove that my WordPress blog from site title?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking now. In the search results, when your site appears, the listing title shows:

```
Site Title - Page Title
```

For example:

```
A Space For Me - Photo Gallery
```

And you don't want the **Page Title** appended to the **Site Title**, is that right?

The simplest solution is to use an SEO plugin, like [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/), which will allow you to modify the default page title rule, or even change the page titles on a per-page basis.

Answer (score -1):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.3

> Meta data profiles
>
> The profile attribute of the HEAD specifies the location of a meta
>   data profile. The value of the profile attribute is a URI. User agents
>   may use this URI in two ways: As a globally unique name. User agents
>   may be able to recognize the name (without actually retrieving the
>   profile) and perform some activity based on known conventions for that
>   profile. For instance, search engines could provide an interface for
>   searching through catalogs of HTML documents, where these documents
>   all use the same profile for representing catalog entries. As a link.
>   User agents may dereference the URI and perform some activity based on
>   the actual definitions within the profile (e.g., authorize the usage
>   of the profile within the current HTML document). This specification
>   does not define formats for profiles.

Comment: Any solution of this problem?

Comment: There is no other solution.Please go ahead your theme and open ( header.php ) file. and Remove the ones you want

Comment: Please  If this answer is correct then vote.@RandomVideos